# Add custom CSS styling to model form django

Tags: python, css, django

I am using a bootstrap variant to help style a model form. There is a certain class I would like one of the fields to be and I have read around on the subject and the general consensus is to add a widget to the ModelForm's meta, like I tried below:

forms.py

```
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MarketingEmails
        fields = ['messageid','subject','body','name','altsubject','utm_source','utm_content','utm_campaign',]
        widgets = {
            'body': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'summernote'}),
        }
```

However this doesn't seem to render onto my template, which is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" action ="">
    {% csrf_token %}        
        <p><label for="id_subject">Subject</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="1000" value="{{rows.subject}}"required /></p>

        <p><label for="id_name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="1000" value="{{rows.name}}"required /></p>

        <p><label for="id_body">Body</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_body" type="text" name="body" maxlength="1000" value="{{rows.body}}"required /></p>

        <p><label for="id_altsubject">Alt Subject</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_altsubject" type="text" name="altsubject" maxlength="1000" value="{{rows.altsubject}}"required /></p>

        <p><label for="id_utm_source">utm_source</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_utm_source" type="text" name="utm_source" maxlength="1000" value="{{rows.utm_source}}"required /></p>

        <p><label for="id_utm_content">utm_content</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_utm_content" type="text" name="utm_content" maxlength="1000" value="{{rows.utm_content}}"required /></p>

        <p><label for="id_utm_campaign">utm_campaign</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_utm_campaign" type="text" name="utm_campaign" maxlength="1000" value="{{rows.utm_campaign}}"required /></p>

        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Is there another way to do this or is there something I have done wrong in my code?

**UPDATE**
I have followed the suggested of Jacek and now it is styled but the information is no longer displaying, this is my new code:

forms.py:

```
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
subject = forms.CharField(
    label = 'Subject',
    max_length = 2000,
    required = True,
    widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {'class': 'summernote', 'name': 'subject'}
        )
    )

... 
class Meta:
    model = MarketingEmails
    fields = ['messageid','subject','body','name','altsubject','utm_source','utm_content','utm_campaign',]
```

views.py:

```
def emailinfo(request, pk):
if request.session.has_key('shortname'):
    shortname =  request.session['shortname']
    form = MarketingEmails.objects.filter(messageid =pk).get()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = EmailForm(instance=form)
        return render(request, 'marketingemails/emailinfo.html',{'shortname': shortname, 'form': form})

    else:
        form = EmailForm(request.POST,instance=form)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('marketingemails:emailinfo', pk = form.messageid)

    return render(request, 'marketingemails/emailinfo.html',{'shortname': shortname, 'form': form})
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('common:login'))
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <form method="POST" action ="">
    {% csrf_token %}        
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}

        {% if field.help_text %}
            {{ field.help_text }}
        {% endif %}

        {% for error in field.errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

forms.py

```
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    subject = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Subject',
        max_length = 1000,
        required = True,
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {'class': 'summernote', 'name': 'subject'}
        )
    )   

    body = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Body',
        max_length = 1000,
        required = True,
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {'class': 'summernote', 'name': 'body'}
        )
    )   
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = MarketingEmails
        fields = ('messageid','subject','body','name', ... )
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from your_app_path.forms import EmailForm

def fname(request):
    ...
    marketing = MarketingEmails.objects.get(...)

    form = EmailForm(instance=marketing) 
    ...

    return render(request, 'yourview.html', { 'form': form })
```

yourview.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}

    {% if field.help_text %}
      {{ field.help_text }}
    {% endif %}

    {% for error in field.errors %}
      {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have set the code up like suggested, and now it is styled but the information is not being displayed on the webpage like it was previously, I have added an update on my code - do you know why this is?

Answer (score 5):

In my templates I use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)  You can add CSS classes or twitter-bootstrap classes. Its really useful

```
<form method='POST' action="/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 {% load widget_tweaks %}
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.first_name |add_class:"customCSS1 customCSS2" }}
 {{ form.second_name |add_class:"form-control customCSS4" }}
</form>
{{ form.media.js }}
```

with this plugin you can style the form as you wish. You could add your `form-control` class or use a personal CSS class like

```
.customCSS1{
  width60%;
  border-radius:5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answer for your question but directly related and I think people looking for it might land here:
You can pass a class attr to a Model Form (not just Form) but you have to watch out not to put it in the `class Meta`:

```
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs):
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    class Meta:
        model = MarketingEmails
        fields = __all__ # or a list of ones you actually want to see
```