# Styling ModelForms in Django won't work

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, python-3.x, django-forms

i wanted to use `UserCreationForm`in Django but i need to embed Bootstrap Classes in it so i decided to override it and unfortunately it doesn't work for styling!

Here is my code

#### forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
password.
"""
error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': ("The two password fields didn't match."),
}
username = forms.CharField(label=("Password"),
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-lg', 'placeholder':'First Name',}))
password1 = forms.CharField(label=("Password"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-lg', 'placeholder':'First Name',}))
password2 = forms.CharField(label=("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-lg', 'placeholder':'First Name',}),
    help_text=("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            code='password_mismatch',
        )
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

#### template.html

```
<div class="container makemargs"><div class="row"><h3 class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">Signup</h3></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-6"><form id="signupForm" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form" role="form">{% csrf_token %}         {{form}}<button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-block signup-btn" type="submit" disabled>Create my account</button></form></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098988/add-custom-css-styling-to-model-form-django/45099039#45099039 asked two hours ago.

Comment: @hansTheFranz didn't work! :-) thank anyway

Comment: my solution? It works. I guarantee it :D

Comment: @hansTheFranz Wow! it works really! add_class didn't but append_attr worked great

Comment: So your question is solved?

Comment: @hansTheFranz yup thanks

Comment: Answer your own Question, so the next person can see what happened and the question does not stayed unanswered. If you do a good job I will up vote it and you get some points ;)

Comment: sure thanks again @hansTheFranz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom CSS styling to model form django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098988/add-custom-css-styling-to-model-form-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @hansTheFranz and his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099039/7337499)
I just used this amazing tool [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) and it worked perfectly.

I had to use `append_attr` instead of `add_class`.

Comment: When you now click on accept answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work on your answer and accept my edit suggestion im Happy ;)

Comment: In general try to accept answers when you liked them or at least up vote them. Since you have 23 Points now (somebody else also upvoted your answer) you can click on the arrow up when you thought something was helpful (for example my answer on the other question, but you don't have to do it there I have enough points :D). This way StackOverflow stays alive and people help each other...

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Comment: Thanks hansTheFranz and Baum_mit_Augen for helping me ,